# Keeping CALayers within bounds of the CALayer container

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am currently trying to build a clock app, and it needs to work across from iPhone 4 all the way to iPads. Naturally, I have a scaling issue. I am noticing that the hands of the clock work well in some devices, and don't work well in other devices. My hands are sublayers of the clock face, and the hands are all anchored at 0.5.

Would someone be able to explain to me what I am missing? I have tried setting the bounds of the hands but it doesn't seem to work.

`secHand.bounds = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I wasn't scaling the clock arms, but I was scaling the clock face.

`minHand.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
minHand.contentsScale = scale;`